# Speeding up JSON file parsing in Android

Tags: android, json

I've been working on an Android application  that reads a JSON file about 3MB in size and displays some of the data on the screen. However, it takes a ridiculous amount of time to load, and most of that time is spent generating the JSON object that includes the whole file. I've looked at a few benchmarks, but I am nowhere near as fast as even the results for the standard JSON parser say I should be. It takes about 20 seconds to build the JSON object, the code is provided below.

```
private String obtainLeaderboardsData(String host) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String URL = "http://" + host + "/api/wow/challenge/region?locale=en_GB";
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://eu.battle.net/api/wow/challenge/region?locale=en_GB");
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(MainActivity.class.toString(), "Failed to download file");
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return builder.toString();
}

private class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Run>> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Run> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        ArrayList<Run> runs = new ArrayList<Run>();
        String[] hosts = {"eu.battle.net"};
        for(String host : hosts) {
            String leaderboardsData = obtainLeaderboardsData(host);
            try {   
                JSONObject leaderboard = new JSONObject(leaderboardsData);
                JSONArray challenges = leaderboard.getJSONArray("challenge");
                for(int i = 0; i < challenges.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject challenge = challenges.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject o_dungeon = challenge.getJSONObject("map");
                    String dungeon = o_dungeon.getString("name");
                    JSONArray groups = challenge.getJSONArray("groups");
                    for(int j = 0; j < groups.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject group = groups.getJSONObject(j);
                        Run run = new Run(group, dungeon);
                        if(run.hours_passed > 0 && run.hours_passed < 72) {
                            runs.add(run);
                        }
                    }       
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(runs, new CustomComparator());
        return runs;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Run> runs) {         
        ListView allList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.allList);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(runs.size());
        for (Run run : runs) {
            HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
            item.put("rank_dungeon_timer_passed", "#" + run.ranking + " " + run.dungeon + " " + run.timer + " (" + run.hours_passed + " hours ago)");
            String members = "";
            for(int i = 0; i < run.members.size(); i++) {
                members = members + run.members.get(i) + "\n";
            }
            item.put("members", members);
            list.add(item);
        }
        String[] from = new String[] {"rank_dungeon_timer_passed", "members"};
        int[] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};
        int nativeLayout = android.R.layout.two_line_list_item;
        allList.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, list, nativeLayout , from, to));
    }
}
```

The line that takes the longest is:

```
JSONObject leaderboard = new JSONObject(leaderboardsData);
```

Is this a wrong way of reading in a full JSON file?

EDIT: Since I'm not using most of the data, is there any way I can add parameters to the URL query to filter out some fields I don't need?

Comment: I don't know the battle.net API, but any chance you could limit your API query to get a smaller response, or do you need the full 3MB of data all at once?

Comment: If you're that slow, you shouldn't parse the file in 1 big chunk.  Parse the file in smaller chunks with a streaming parser.

Comment: Might want to avoid `members = members + run.members.get(i) + "\n";` as well and use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: are you sure it isn't the downloading of the file that is slow? are you certain 20 seconds are spent solely in `new JSONObject(leaderboardsData)`?

Comment: FWIW downloading that file to my laptop took 12 seconds using `wget` - no parsing. `3,155,312    290KB/s   in 12s`

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing it's parsing a lot more info in that call than you need. I do all my JSON parsing through [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/). It's very fast and easy to set up. If you have time to test it out, it might make your life easier from here on out.

Comment: I'll try that out. Another thing I've been looking into is possibly hosting the relevant data from the API on a webserver and running a cron job every few minutes to update this file. As you can see I only really need less than 1% of the data.

Comment: That would definitely be the best solution, as it'll reduce network traffic, save on battery, etc.